# recover the 0 in #<SB-IMPL::PROCESS :EXITED 0>

Tags: sbcl

on my Debian wheezy with SBCL:

1) Alsaplayer play a CD audio:
    * (run-program "/usr/bin/alsaplayer" '("-q" "CD.cdda") :wait nil)

```
#<SB-IMPL::PROCESS 7199 :RUNNING>
```

2) ps tells me that the audio CD plays: (EXITED 0)
    * (run-program "/bin/ps" '("-C" "alsaplayer"))

```
#<SB-IMPL::PROCESS :EXITED 0>
```

Problem:
I want to recover the values 0 in the part 2) 
but let's say that I put the result of 2) in the variable var0.

```
* (type-of var0)

SB-IMPL::PROCESS
```

I would like to know if there is a direct way to get the 0 ?
to recover it I did:

```
*(setf str0 (format nil "~a" var0))

"#<PROCESS :EXITED 0>"

* (aref str0 18)
#\0
```

but it doesn't seem very clever ?

Thanks in advance for any clue.

Gerard

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
(sb-ext:process-exit-code var0)
```

It's in the SBCL manual.